# Flutter SSO (Single Sign On) through SAML

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, saml, flutter-ios

I want to add authentication through **SAML** in flutter app.But I didn't find any helpful doc or package for integration with flutter.

So any suggestion will be of great help.